# Move vertically (scroll up) one div within another one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

How to move the content of the inner div up, without click any buttons, I mean, like an animation. And is there any way to trigger an event when the animation is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to use is a `Callback`. Specifically the one built in to [`.animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

```
$('div').animate({top:-50},1000,function() {
    alert('Animation is finished!');
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/koolvin/YGBvb/

Or perhaps you meant something more along the lines of this:
http://jsfiddle.net/koolvin/uFwap

```
$('div').animate({scrollTop:100},1000,function() {
    alert('Animation is finished!');
});
```

After reviewing your comment, it looks like this is what you want:
http://jsfiddle.net/koolvin/uFwap/17/

Comment: I'm sorry for my lack of knowledge, I was trying to do your solution but I'm getting "Object expected" error, I placed the script right after the div tag. Also, imagine the effect like the credits of a movie, where the outer div is the display, and the inner div the content, the content should not be shown if it is outside the outer div. Please advice.

Comment: No problem. Always willing to help.